# Searching for Plant Growth Board Game with Stacking

Tags: identify-this-game

I am trying to find a game that is similar to Photosynthesis. Unless I am completely misremembering, it plays very similar to Photosynthesis, with a central area that everybody competes in and a sun that rotates around the board. However, instead of using 2-d cut-outs of trees, as Photosynthesis has, this game had stackable game pieces representing roots, vines, flowers etc.
Does anything like this exist?
[image]

I never saw the game in person or played, I believe I saw it on boardgamegeek.com. Takenoko looks the most similar, but the actual game play area was very tight and there were no meeple-type pieces. It seemed like it was a square grid with dimensions of ~7-9 square units (whatever the size of the pieces/ tiles were) and I vaguely remember the pieces having some height to them, like little plastic majong tiles. They may have snapped together, similar to legos, but I'm more uncertain of that last detail than the others.
The sun would "shine" on the gameboard from the 4 cardinal directions and higher stacked tiles would block the light for anything behind it.

Comment: When did you play it? Can you describe any of the mechanics of the game (like how you earned points, what purpose the sun served, was the board square or hexagonal, extra)?

Comment: Can you describe the decoration of the pieces or the board at all?  Were they mostly plain, with simple designs? Vibrant colors like Photosynthesis? Pastels?  The additional details you've added so far are good, but every little bit helps.  Even when you saw the game helps - if you saw the game five years ago it would rule out a vast swath of new games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [Arboria](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/231368/arboria)

[image]

> players play cards to grow flowers, move the sun, move the cloud, create rain, or destroy opponents' flowers. On your turn, play three cards from all available (yours and the unused ones from your preceding opponents). Once the sun has circled the board, the game is over. Points are allocated by multiplying the height of your biggest flowers by the number of same color flowers in a row.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure that is it, though I remember the game pieces differently. Now we'll see how hard it is to get my hands on a copy. Luckily, I just ordered Photosynthesis, which the consensus seems to indicate is a little better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The only game I can think of that involves plants growing by stacking of pieces is [Takenoko](https://store.us.asmodee.com/catalogue/takenoko_770/). It doesn't fit perfectly but I can't think of any other game at all that involved building plants with stacking pieces.